# Firebase And Other NodeJS Hosting Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, firebase

We're developing our web app on google cloud and we are using firebase as a database and auth functions. Can we deploy our app on AWS or Azure? Is it a problem using firebase?

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad question , but generally speaking if your app uses firebase and you deploy on AWS or Azure it works there is no problem due to firebase being a database.

Thanks